# For $y=x+\epsilon$, how can we obtain the SD of $x$ when $y\gt t$

Tags: r, normal-distribution, bivariate, truncated-normal-distribution

Given that
$$
\begin{align}
x&\sim N(0,\sigma^2=h^2)\\
\epsilon&\sim N(0, \sigma^2=(1-h^2))\\
y&=x+\epsilon
\end{align}
$$

Then $y$ is essentially a bivariate normal distribution with $\sum=\left( \begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&0\\ \end{array}\right)$
(*thank you whuber*)

If we select the top $t\%$ of y as cases, then we can obtain the mean and variance of y for case and control as follow

```
liability.info <- function(t){
    require(truncnorm)
    case.mean <- dnorm(qnorm(t))/t
    case.var <- vtruncnorm(a=qnorm(t, lower.tail=F), b=Inf, mean=0, sd=1)
    control.mean <- -dnorm(qnorm(t))/(1-t)
    control.var <- vtruncnorm(a=-Inf,b=qnorm(t, lower.tail=F), mean=0, sd=1)
    return(data.frame(Control.Mean=control.mean, Control.Var=control.var, Case.Mean=case.mean, Case.Var=case.var))
}
```

**The question is, can we calculate the mean and variance of $x$ for case and control?**

According to whuber, for bivariate normal variables, the regression is linear. Therefore that the mean of the truncated $x$ is a linear function of the mean of the truncated $y$.

So all the remains is the variance. **Is it possible for us to calculate variance of $x$ for cases and controls?**

---

> Keeping the original question below for the record
>   *Through simulation, it seems like by multiplying the mean of $y_{case}$ and $y_{control}$ by $h^2$, we can obtain the corresponding mean of $x_{case}$ and $x_{control}$ (but without mathematical proof)*
>   [image: Mean of X against adjusted Mean of Y]
>
> *However, when it comes to the standard deviation, we are not sure how to obtain the sd of $x_{case}$ and $x_{control}$ from $y$.*
>
> *Based on our simulation, $y_{case}$ and $y_{control}$ follows the truncated normal distribution but $x_{case}$ and $x_{control}$ still follows the normal distribution. So it is unclear whether if it is possible for us to estimate the sd of $x_{case}$ and $x_{control}$ given we know $h^2$, $t$ and sd of $y_{case}$ and $y_{control}$.*
>
> *Thus, is it possible for us to estimate the sd of $x_{case}$ and $x_{control}$ given we know $h^2$, $t$ and sd of $y_{case}$ and $y_{control}$? And on a side note, is there any mathematical proof to the relationship of the means? Thank you.*

Comment: This problem is solved by regressing $x$ on $y$.  Since for bivariate normal variables the regression is linear, it follows immediately (from linearity of expectation) that the mean of the truncated $x$ is a linear function of the mean of the truncated $y$.

Comment: Thank you whuber, that make a lot of sense. I will try to restructure the question to make it clearer. Thank you very much!